# Unable to figure out the Voltage levels of LED Strip Controller LPD8806

Tags: arduino, led-strip

For each of the [LPD8806](https://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/lpd8806%20english.pdf), I am unable to figure out what should be the voltage levels of the Data In (DI) and Clock In (CI) pins?

I am trying to use this individually addressable [LED Strip here](https://www.adafruit.com/products/306).

I know that VDD has to be 5V but cannot figure out the voltage level of the Data In (DI) and Clock In (CI) on each of the LPD8806s?

Or is anyone aware of a similar product of individually addressable LEDs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LPD8806 is a poorly documented chip, but it has been reversed engineered quite a bit. Based on the [Solarbotics version](https://solarbotics.com/product/60526/), they and others note that it can be powered from 2.7V to 5V. Of course, at 2.7V, you won't get a bright blue or green. It can be powered from 3.3V easily.

The logic levels are relative to VCC, of course. Most people see issues with 3.3V logic at 5V, meaning the logic will typically be VCC * 0.7 or 0.75 minimum. That's 3.5V or 3.75V, when powered at 5V.

For the most part, the LPD8806 strips are old technology. Most have moved onto WS2811/WS2812b, or APA102 or APA104 based strips.

Comment: I will mark this as the answer as I appreciate the pointers towards WS2811/WS2812b, or APA102 or APA104. I am looking for individually addressable LED strips though.

Comment: @user1406716 the WS and APA **are** the ICs used in individually addressable LEDs and LED strips. The ICs are just ***INSIDE*** the LED. Ada fruit calls them the Neo Pixel and Dot Star, respectfully.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear. The datasheet specifies Vin between -0.4V and (Vout+0.4V). But Vout is not specified, but a reasonable assumption is that they intended to state Vdd (which has a maximum of 5.5V). Basically, it will operate with 5V signals. Since the datasheet does not give the logic thresholds for Vil and Vih it is not possible to determine if it will work with 3V or 3.3V logic.

Comment: VOUT must be between 0.8-5V range. But Vout is not the logic levels.